# Feasibility of using Ring Signatures with CoinJoin Technique

Tags: cryptography, c++, coinjoin

There is a Ring Signature implementation in C++ by Libbitcoin team. We can find the details in the following [GitHub](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system/blob/bef130bdc8c57808dceab99d6867f3c58acf4e92/include/bitcoin/system/math/ring_signature.hpp) repository. Is it feasible to use Monero like Ring Signatures together with the CoinJoin Technique in Bitcoin without a soft fork on the core protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Using ring signatures off-chain to form a coinjoin transaction sounds hard, especially since because BTC doesn't have ring signature support without a hard fork or a soft fork.

You may find [Cashfusion](https://github.com/cashshuffle/spec/blob/master/CASHFUSION.md), an instance of CoinJoin shuffling, interesting, it's fully applicable to BTC and it uses TOR, which is simpler than Ring Signatures.

Comment: Thank you so much @MCCCS. Cashfusion and Cashsuffle is very interesting. I will check it out!!